# In Python 2 do we need a self keyword for a function even if the function isn't part of a class?

Tags: python, python-2.x

So I'm looking through some old python 2 code and I see this function

```
def manage_addMapSamlPlugin(self, id, title='', delegate_path='', REQUEST=None):
  """ Factory method to instantiate a MapSamlPlugin """
  # Make sure we really are working in our container (the
  # PluggableAuthService object)
  self = self.this()                         
  # Instantiate the adapter object
  lmp = MapSamlPlugin(id, title=title, delegate_path=delegate_path )
  self._setObject(id, lmp)
  if REQUEST is not None:
    REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect('%s/manage_main' % self.absolute_url())
```

Now this function is outside of a class, the code compiles and doesn't give any errors. My understanding is that the self keyword in this case is just anything that gets passed in, but self.this() and self._setObject(id, lmp) that shouldn't be a thing right? Shouldn't the compiler throw an error? The code is run on a terminal in a ssh server I don't know what compiler it uses.
At the end of the file this is where the function gets called.

```
def initialize(context):
  registerMultiPlugin(MapSamlPlugin.meta_type)
  context.registerClass(
    MapSamlPlugin,
    constructors=(manage_addMapSamlPluginForm, manage_addMapSamlPlugin),
    permission=ManageUsers,
    icon=os.path.join(mgr_dir, "saml_icon.png"),
    visibility=None,
    )
```

And this is also a standalone function "context" isn't derived from any imports or class.

Comment: Why would it give errors? `self` is not a keyword and not even a built-in name. It is simply a convention. But it has no special meaning whatsoever. You can also replace `self` with `baz` in classes...

Comment: `self` is not a keyword. `self` is the name *conventionally* given to the first positional parameter of methods, which will be passed the instance implicitly when the method is invoked on an instance.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is an important clue:

```
def manage_addMapSamlPlugin(self, id, title='', delegate_path='', REQUEST=None):
  """ Factory method to instantiate a MapSamlPlugin """
  # Make sure we really are working in our container (the
  # PluggableAuthService object)
  self = self.this()
```

`self` is expected to be an object which has a `this()` method -- it sounds like that method returns a `PluggableAuthService` object.  If you grep the rest of the code for `def this` you'll probably find it.  Looking for `class PluggableAuthService` might also shed some light.

If you call this function and pass it a `self` that doesn't implement the expected interface, you'll get an `AttributeError` at runtime.  Since there are no type annotations here, there's not really a way to catch errors statically (at "compile time" -- although typically compiling Python doesn't in itself enforce any static type checks).

My suspicion is that this function was originally a method of that class, and got refactored out of it for some reason (maybe as the first step in some larger refactor that was never finished).  A class method works just fine if you yank it out of a class, provided that you explicitly provide the `self` parameter when you call it.

Comment: The only PluggableAuthService from searching the file is from the imports. from Products.PluggableAuthService.plugins.BasePlugin import BasePlugin
from Products.PluggableAuthService import registerMultiPlugin  Does this mean I will need to create a class for PluggableAuthService or would it just work and find what it needs from the imports?

Comment: *I will need to create a class for PluggableAuthService* -- in order to *do what*?  It looks like this function gets called by that `registerClass` function.  You should probably go figure out how that works before messing around with trying to call this particular function on its own.  Better yet, if you don't have to modify this code for any particular reason, just walk away from it and never think of it again.  :P

Comment: If you do need to try to maintain this code, my first step would be type-annotating the whole thing (using the comment syntax that mypy supports with Python 2).  It's completely inscrutable without annotations since the parameters need to have specific types but there's not any clear indication of what those types are.

Comment: I'm not able to use mypy my version is Python 2.4, are there other libraries I can use? Tried pip install 'mypy[python2]'

Comment: Install Python3 and use it to run mypy on your Python2 code. 
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-type-check-my-python-2-code  If you want to maintain this code, you should ultimately be aiming to migrate it to Python3; mypy is really helpful with that too since type annotations will help you not break things as you do the migration.